# How to split a list of urls by pattern?

Tags: web-scraping, pattern-recognition

I crawled a list of urls from a website. I want to cluster these urls to groups. Then I can generate a sitemap for this site. Similar urls should goto the same group.

```
IN [1]: http://www.example.org/s/daily/2013-12-09/1392994518.html
OUT[1]: http://www.example.org/s/daily/${date:%Y-%m-%d}/${date:%s}.html

IN [2]: http://www.example.org/torvalds/linux/commit/3bd7bf1f0fe14f591c089ae61bbfa9bd356f178a
OUT[2]: http://www.example.org/torvalds/linux/commit/${sha1}
```

Do you have any ideas? Is there same software package I can use?

Comment: If the patterns are predefined, you can use regular expressions, otherwise you will have to provide a more rigorous definition of similarity.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the URLs that have high frequency of flow into them. Once you've identified these, eliminate those that have low flow (or no) flow to other pages on the site. This later group will likely be things like terms of use, privacy policy.

The former are the anchor points to the division of the site. Goto the anchor pages and use the text in the  line as the name of the division. Then check the URLs that flow out of the anchors to other pages on the site. If they don't flow to another anchor point, they belong to this division.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any algorithm to solve this problem? Which book/article/blog do you suggest?